# why wso2 api manager gateway respond in unknown binary format after each 2 successful hit to specific api?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

when I send requests to api manager gateway(port:8243) for specific api(actually when I call an api ) repeatedly,after second successful call(https://apigw.ir/public/v1/otherInfo/client) and with right response(in json format), in third api call ,api manager gateway respond in unknown binary format and here is a picture :
[image]

what is the problem ?

Comment: Probably that is coming from your Backend. Did you verify that it's not generated from the actual Backend?

Comment: @ycr this not come from backend , is it possible to issue with nginx conf ?

Comment: Try enabling Wirelogs to verify. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#enable-gateway-wire-logs if you can add the complete log after enabling wire logs.